# How to find all possible path going out from two nodes?

Tags: graph, networkx

I have created a graph in networkx,

> G.add_path(['vineet','home','Revenant'])
>
> G.add_path(['vineet','home','Poison'])
>
> G.add_path(['vineet','theater','Mask'])
>
> G.add_path(['ramesh','home','Revenant'])

In this graph i want to find all the nodes connected to 'vineet' and 'home' i.e. output should come 'Revenant' and 'Poison'. Similarly for 'ramesh','home' output should be 'Revenant'

Comment: Your question is incorrect. Since in your example, `home` is connected to vineet and home is also connected to ramesh, then for `vineet` and `home` you would also get `ramesh`. Now with that logic, you will also get `theater` and `Mask`

Comment: Actually i want all nodes that are connected to a set of nodes, like here for 'vineet' and 'home' i want 'Revenant' and 'Poison', similarly for 'ramesh' and 'home' 'Revenant' should come.

Comment: Is your graph directed or not ?